# rank of product of 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Please have me with the following question:

$A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix with rank $m$, $B$ is a $n \times  p$ matrix with rank $p$. Given that $p<m<n$. Is there condition of $A$,$B$ that $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=p$?

An part of answer is here
[Full-rank condition for product of two matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94287/full-rank-condition-for-product-of-two-matrices)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I realize this post was made nearly 2 years ago, but I'll answer this for the sake of anyone searching the web for an answer.

---

Note that $\text{ker}(B) \subset \text{ker}(AB)$, so $\text{nullity}(B) \leq \text{nullity}(AB)$. Using the relationship between rank and nullity, we have that $$n - \text{rank}(B) = \text{nullity}(B) \leq \text{nullity}(AB) = p - \text{rank}(AB)$$
$$\implies \text{rank}(AB) \leq \text{rank}(B) - (n - p) < \text{rank}(B) = p$$
Hence, there is no condition which can be imposed on $A, B$ which will make $\text{rank}(AB) = p$.

Comment: Shouldn't rank(B) + nullity(B) = p instead of n?