# Rank of Products of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, matrix-rank

This is somewhat of a reference request.

In several posts on the rank of products of matrices (e.g. [Full-rank condition for product of two matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94287/full-rank-condition-for-product-of-two-matrices?rq=1)), it is stated that

$$ \mathrm{rank}(AB) = \mathrm{rank}(B) - \dim \big(\mathrm{N}(A) \cap \mathrm{R}(B)\big)$$

It appears that this is a classic result, though I am not familiar with it. If anyone can point me to a textbook that discusses it and other rank inequalities, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you denote $N(A)$ and  $R(B)$?

Comment: $N(A) = \mbox{nullity of A}$ and $R(B)$ is the rank of $B$, I think.

Comment: $\textsf{N}(A)$ is the nullspace of $A$ and $\textsf{R}(B)$ is the range or image of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there exists a $v$ with $B u = v$ and $A v = 0$. What is $AB u$? Can you take it from there?

EDIT: typo.

Comment: Thanks! I guess you mean $Av = 0$. It looks like the result comes from counting bases, but I did linear algebra a long time ago and am quite rusty. If you know of a good reference book that would be very helpful!

Comment: Every vector that is in both $N(A)$ and $R(B)$ will decrease the rank of $AB$ by one. The rank of $AB$ cannot be larger than $B$ in the first place, so you get the desired result. I'm sorry I don't know a direct reference for this fact. I'd be surprised if you didn't find it in any (vector space-based) linear algebra textbook.