# Rank of product of two matrices over an arbitrary field of characteristic zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $A \in k^{m \times n}$,
$B \in k^{n \times m}$.

There are several posts in MSE asking for a proof for **claim 1**:
$\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min\{\operatorname{rank}(A), \operatorname{rank}(B)\}$, where the product is defined, so $B$, more generally, belongs to $k^{n \times p}$.

> **Question 1:** Is claim 1 valid over any field of zero characteristic? (not just $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).

Then we can consider the special case where $B=A^T$.

For this special case there are posts asking for a proof for **claim 2**: $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(AA^T) = \operatorname{rank}(A^TA)$.

It was mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-operatornamerankata-operatornameranka-for-any-a-in-m-m-times-n?noredirect=1&lq=1) that this equality holds over $\mathbb{R}$ but not over $\mathbb{C}$, with the following [counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215145/rank-of-product-of-a-matrix-and-its-transpose/682249#682249): $ A=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & i \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
$,
$A^T = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\ 
i & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.
Here $AA^T=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$
and
$A^TA=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & i \\ 
i & -1
\end{pmatrix}$.
Here $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(A^T)=1$, $\operatorname{rank}(AA^T)=0$,
$\operatorname{rank}(A^TA)=1$.

We see that claim 1 holds, while claim 2 does not hold in general.

If claim 1 is valid over any zero characteristic field, then in particular we have **claim 3**:
$\operatorname{rank}(AA^T) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A)$ and
$\operatorname{rank}(A^TA) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A)$
(if it is true that $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A^T)$).

I have constructed $A \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)^{4 \times 2}$ of rank $2$ such that $AA^T \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)^{4 \times 4}$ is of rank $\geq 3$, which would contradict claim 3! This was a surprise. I wonder what will go wrong in a proof over a zero characteristic field different from $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.
I will present the counterexample later; wishes to check again if I have no errors in my calculations.

See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3283477/rank-of-products-of-matrices) question.

Thank you very much!

---

Please tell me where is my error:
$k=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
2x+1 & 2y \\ 
-2y & -2x \\
2x & 2y \\
-26 & -2x+1
\end{pmatrix}$.

$A$ has rank two, since $\begin{pmatrix} 
2x+1 & 2y \\ 
-2y & -2x 
\end{pmatrix}$ is invertible over $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$: the determinant is $-2x-4x^2+4y^2$.

I now see that I had an error in my calculation, and the $3 \times 3$ minor of $AA^T$ I was considering has zero determinant...
[image]

---

I really apologize.. Thank you very much for your help, it was good to make sure that claim 1 holds over any field (hence also claim 3).

Comment: The first claim is true over all fields. The characteristic of the field is irrelevant. As for your supposed counterexample to the third claim, would you please exhibit it?

Comment: @user1551, thank you for your comment. I will exhibit the counterexample in an half an hour.

Comment: (i) row rank = column rank holds over any field and (ii) $\text{rank}\big(AB)\leq \text{rank}\big(A)$ holds over any field since the former is in the column space of the latter.  Thus claim 1 holds over any field.

Comment: @user8675309, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality holds over **any** field, regardless of characteristic.

If $M$ is an $r\times s$ matrix with coefficients in the field $k$, then the rank of $M$ is the dimension of the range of $M$, viewed as a linear transformation $k^s\to k^r$.

If $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix and $B$ is an $m\times p$ matrix, then the range of $AB$ is contained in the range of $A$; which gives $\mathrm{rank}(AB)\leq\mathrm{rank}(A)$. As for $\mathrm{rank}(AB)\leq \mathrm{rank}(B)$, this follows from the Rank-Nullity Theorem (which holds over any field): the rank of $AB$ is equal to $p-\dim(\mathbf{N}(AB))$. The rank of $B$ is $p-\dim(\mathbf{N}(B))$. Since $\mathbf{N}(B)\subseteq \mathbf{N}(AB)$, we have $\dim(\mathbf{N}(B))\leq \dim(\mathbf{N}(AB))$, so
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{rank}(AB) &= p-\dim(\mathbf{N}(AB))\\
&\leq p-\dim(\mathbf{N}(B))\\
&= \mathrm{rank}(B).
\end{align*}$$
Since $\mathrm{rank}(AB)\leq \mathrm{rank}(A)$, and $\mathrm{rank}(AB)\leq\mathbf{rank}(B)$, you conclude $\mathbf{rank}(AB)\leq\min(\mathrm{rank}(A),\mathrm{rank}(B))$.

Note that nothing in the above proof uses the characteristic of $k$.

While claim 2 does not follow for $\mathbb{C}$, the corresponding claim is that $\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(AA^*) = \mathrm{rank}(A^*A)$, where $A^*$ is the *conjugate* transpose of $A$; this turns into the stated equality for real numbers.

Comment: More simply for $\operatorname{rank}(AB)\le\operatorname{rank}(B)$: take a basis $(v_1,\dots,v_r)$ of the range of $B,$ and notice that $A(v_1),\dots,A(v_r)$ span the range of $AB.$

Comment: @AnneBauval, thank you!

Comment: @AnneBauval I used the nullspaces because of the post linked at the end, which seeks a proof of $\mathrm{rank}(AB) = \mathrm{rank}(B)-\dim(\mathbf{N}(A)\cap\mathbf{R}(B))$, but sure.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thank you for your proof.

Comment: @user237522 who said it did? That comment has nothing to do with my answer, so why are you making it here?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I apologize. I now deleted it. Just wanted to give an example over a 
 field different from $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @user237522 The result for $\mathbb{R}$ and for $\mathbb{C}$ rely on the fact that the transpose/conjugate transpose is the adjoint linear transformation relative to the standard inner product in each case. Fields of positive characteristic do not have positive definite inner products, so the notion of adjoint does not exist.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to use the rank-nullity theorem here. $\text{rank}(AB) \le \text{min}(\text{rank}(A), \text{rank}(B))$ not only holds over any field of any characteristic, it holds even if $A, B$ are linear operators on infinite-dimensional vector spaces, and the ranks can be infinite.

Here is the abstract argument. Let $U, V, W$ be three vector spaces and $B : U \to V, A : V \to W$ be two linear operators. Now:

1. $\text{im}(AB)$ is a subspace of $\text{im}(A)$, so $\text{rank}(AB) \le \text{rank}(A)$.
2. $\text{im}(AB)$ is the image of $\text{im}(B)$ under $A$ so it is a quotient space of $\text{im}(B)$, so $\text{rank}(AB) \le \text{rank}(B)$.

(In the infinite rank case we need the axiom of choice, I guess.)

Comment: Rank-Nullity holds in the infinite dimensional case as well, and could be used to show that the dimension of the image is less than or equal than the dimension of the domain, though of course you can get that (assuming AC) by noting that if $T(v_1),\ldots, T(v_k)$ are linearly independent, then $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @Arturo: well, in the additive form, but the subtractive form doesn't make sense.

Comment: That is certainly true.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thank you for your proof.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thank you for the discussions with Anne Bauval and Qiaochu Yuan; interesting.